# Save to listview then send as array blackberry

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

Here's my app flow, there'll be a textfield where the user can enter an email address, after entering an email address, the email address is then inserted/saved to a listview below it. So after saving the email addresses to the listview I want to pass it on stackmob as array. How do I do that?

The layout of the app is that there's a textfield and submit button above then listview at the bottom, and and add member button at the toolbar. So the user taps the add member button, the system dialog pops up then the user enters an email address after entering the email, the email is then added to the listview. However, the textfield above is where the user enters his project name, so when the user taps the submit button I want the project name and the members (as array) added in the listview to be saved in stackmob

Answer (score 0):

When you are displaying data on a `ListView`, you are in fact adding the data to a model. The `ListView` feeds itself automatically from this model. An easy way to do this could be using a [`QListDataModel`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__qlistdatamodel.html) to store your email addresses, then fetch them when needed via `size()` and `value()` methods on your model.